# ffmpeg: map audio and subtitle stream of (different) specific language only

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, stream, mapping, subtitle

I have a bunch of video files with multiple audio and subtitle streams (in different languages). The streams contain metadata specifying which stream is which langauge. I want to copy all files but maintaining only the spanish audio streams, and the english subtitle streams (and the video stream of course).

Unfortunately, not all videos contain the same language streams at the same index, so instead of using something like `-map 0:a:2` I am trying to select the streams based on metadata.

However, if I try the following: (based on answers found in similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40937172/mapping-streams-by-language-in-ffmpeg) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46769419/ffmpeg-choosing-audio-streams-by-language))

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:v -map 0:a:m:language:spa -map 0:s:m:language:eng -c copy output.mkv`

It still copies the **first** audio and **first** subtitle stream, no matter which stream is which language. In other words, this behaves just like `-map 0:v -map 0:a:0 -map 0:s:0` which isn't what I need.

Is there a different `map` argument I can use to make sure it picks **only the spanish audio stream** and **only the english subtitle stream**, regardless of their index in the input file?

Comment: You need a (> 13 Feb 2019) git binary for this syntax to work as expected.

Comment: @Gyan Thanks but mine is built from source (I'm using homebrew on macOs) and my ffmpeg version is from June 23rd, 2019

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: @Gyan How? Or full log of what, exactly?

Comment: Of the command you tried. Redirect stderr to a file and link to that, or add -report to your command and share that.

Comment: Hi  @RocketNuts, have you figured it out? Please give an answer, and I'll upvote for you.